# Exponential random variables P(X>a>b)

Tags: probability

How do we calculate the probability an exponential random variable X is greater than constant a and greater than constant b, in other words P(X>a>b). P(X>a) is $\int_a^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx $

Comment: $P(X>a>b)$ has to be replaced by $P(X>max(a,b)).$

Answer (score 1):

You have to reformulate your problem as

$$P(X>max(a,b))=\int_{max(a,b)}^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda x}dx=e^{-\lambda max(a,b)}.$$

Comment: can we get rid of the max somehow?

Comment: No, unless you have the information $a \geq b$ or $b\geq a$. It is not rare at all that an "end result" includes a "max".